# How can I set static asset cache-control headers while using PHP on Heroku?

Tags: php, caching, heroku, http-headers

Is this worth trying to accomplish or should I move the assets to CloudFront (or some other CDN)?

Based on past experience, I'm hesitant to go down the CDN route with this project. I tried using a rake task to minify and concatenate my assets, then upload them to the CloudFront. However, when I deployed the project (now containing the rake task) Heroku decided that my app was now ROR and not PHP and the app was toast.